# How to change background color of Card on TouchableOpacity onPress

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I am using **Card** element  **inside TouchableOpacity**.

When i press it, Card background color is too much annoying w.r.t opacity.

when i **remove borderRadius** , this **problem doesn't occure**.

when i **use borderRadius**  ,this **problem occurs**

I have seen all props of components i am using but nothing worked for me.

**Problem:**

When i use borderRadius in Card containerStyle ,TouchableOpacity color is not matched with Card color. approximately oppossite.

how can i give the same color so when card is pressed ,no card white background color is shown ?

**Component.js**

```
               <TouchableOpacity>
                            <Card
                            containerStyle={styles.MainCardStyle}
                            transparent>
                                <CardItem
                                    cardBody
                                    >
                                    <View style= 
                                       {styles.cardContentStyle}>
                                        <Image
                                            style={styles.iconStyle}
                                            resizeMode="contain"
                                            source= 
                                   {require('../../assets/database.png')}
                                        />
                                        <Text style= 
                               {styles.cardTextStyle}>Setting</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </CardItem>
                            </Card>
             </TouchableOpacity>
```

**styles.js**

```
export const styles=({
    MainCardStyle: {
         borderRadius: 16,

    },
    cardContentStyle: {
        flexDirection: 'row',

    },
```

**Actual output**

[image: Actual Output]

**Desired Output**

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: touchable Highlight can help! i guess

Comment: @Rizwanatta, instead of TouchableOpacity ???

Comment: yes see this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight

Comment: TouchableHeighlight didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Put the TouchableOpacity inside the card and use:

style={ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject }

of cause StyleSheet has to be imported

Comment: what is .absoluteFillObject   .  is it prop of TouchableOpacity or Stylesheet.  where to write it. please clearify your answer

Comment: just a simple way to say that an element should take all the space it can get. The prop looks like this <TouchableOpacity style={ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject }>

Comment: Little mistake of mine, it should be style={{ ... }}

Comment: Sorry man, it didn't worked. even touchableopacity is  not showing any touch effect.

Comment: You can also write the card component yourself, it isn't that much much work and better maintainable like this.

Comment: can you please tell me     how ?

Comment: newbie to react-native